# Docker compose push failed with unexpected end of JSON input: ""

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-registry

I have set up the docker registry at DigitalOcean to deploy my django application.
I have installed the `doctl` and setup the API credentials.
If I run the command as:
`doctl auth list`
i can see my `auth` as the current one, which has the `Read` and `Write` permission.
But now, when I try to run the command as:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml push
```

I get the error as:

> ERROR: error parsing HTTP 400 response body: unexpected end of JSON
> input: ""

Here's my `docker-compose.staging.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/pythonist-do:web
    command: gunicorn Pythonist.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/pythonist-do:nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  acme:
```

Comment: This issue looks similar to yours: https://github.com/SUSE/Portus/issues/1511

Comment: @Mogi try to login with `docker login` and get `Login Succeeded` but still getting the same issue on `push`

Answer (score 15):

You need to change the image tag

Instead of

***registry.digitalocean.com/registry-name:tag***

use this

***registry.digitalocean.com/registry-name/image-name:tag***